# How to get music disc 11

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been farming creepers for music discs but I can't find the disc 11. Is it even possible to get? I don't want to use creative or commands to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a skeleton kill the creeper for you. If it does, you have a chance at getting this disc (or another).

Comment: He's been farming creepers for a while. It will take a while for him to even get it.

Comment: @MarkGiraffe no where does it imply hes even tried skeletons

Comment: @Penguin You need skeletons to get music discs from creepers.

Comment: @Dabbingsdednow ??? What? I'm aware, Idk how I couldn't be I posted the answer.

Comment: Sorry, just the way I formatted the question .

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a dungeon, then get to a chest. There are chances you will end up earning the music disc.

> Source: https://www.digminecraft.com/decoration_recipes/make_music_disc_11.php